# javascript - what exactly is this line of code doing?

Tags: javascript

Today I found a typo in some code, but no error was being thrown, and it seems the code passes just fine through the compiler. 
I'd be curious to know exactly what it does though !

```
let y = {}
y.test?'foo':bar = 100
```

My guess is that it is saying 'if y.test is truthy, then return 'foo', otherwise create (dangerously) a variable named bar, set it's value to 100 and return that instead'. 
Is that correct ?

Comment: you're right with your assumption

Comment: ok thanks for your help !

Comment: you are right, in this case return is bar = 100

Comment: Conditional if statement to return either y.test='foo' if set or int 100 and assigned to bar variable.